# Не отображается рамка вокруг TextView

Tags: android, textview

Хотелось бы сделать рамку вокруг элемента `TextView`, создал `xml` файл для описания рамки, её размеров и цвета. Потому добавил её к уже созданному элементу как `android:backgorund"@drawble/rounded"`, но рамки все равно нет при запуске приложения

Xml описания рамки

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="#FFF" />

        <corners android:radius="20dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="5dip"
            android:color="#A5D" />

    </shape>
</selector>
```

xml описания самого элемента

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="104dp"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:text="Кошка, которая гуляла сама по себе"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.556"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Opisanietxt" />
```

Поясните пожалуйста где я не прав, а то действительно не пойму, вроде все правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList), `<selector>` должен содержать один или несколько `<item>`, поэтому нужно, либо обернуть в `<item>`, если нужен таки `<selector>`, либо убрать его:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFF" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#A5D" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Спасибо,это действительно помогло